# $\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

---

I tried putting $x=\sin \theta$ and changing the limits from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$and i got  $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^2\theta\ln \sin \theta d\theta$ i cannot further solve it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use beta function and show that
$$\int_0^1\dfrac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{{2}}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha+2}{2})}$$
then your integral is
$$\dfrac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^1\dfrac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$
in $\alpha=2$.

Comment: Can we solve it without beta function?

Comment: Can we solve it without beta function?

Comment: See duplicated link. there are two answers there.